# Two objects with mass m with charge q connected to spring

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

I am taking Physics 201 on Yale Open Courses. I having trouble with the 5th problem in the problem set 1, which says as follows:

> Two sphere of mass m and negligible size are connected to two identical springs of force constant k as shown in Figure 1. The separation is a. When charged to q Coulombs each, the separation doubles. (i) What is k in terms of q,a,and ε0? (ii) Find k if the separation goes to a/2 when the charges are ±q. (iii) In case (i) suppose the charge on the right is held fixed while that on the left is displaced by a tiny amount x and released. Find the resorting force F = −kex and the (angular) frequency ω of small oscillations. (I call the effective force constant for oscillations as ke to distinguish it from the k for the springs.)

I am having trouble with question iii; I understand the how to approach the problem but after the Taylor Expansion it seems like they are dropping terms without reason ( specifically: ka/2 and the first term in the taylor expansion(1)). I tried many ways but none of them seem to work out.

Here is their solution:

\begin{align}
F_{\text{tot}} =& −k(−\frac{a}{2} + x) − \frac{1}{4\pi\varepsilon}\frac{q^2}{(2a − x)^2} \\
=& \frac{ka}{2} − kx − \frac{1}{4\pi\varepsilon}\frac{q^2}{4a^2}\frac{1}{(1-\frac{x}{2a})^2} \\
=& \frac{ka}{2}−kx− \frac{q^2}{16\pi\varepsilon a^2}(1 + 2\frac{x}{2a} +\dots) \\
=& −\left(k + \frac{q^2}{16\pi\epsilon_0 a^3} \right)x  \\
≡& −k_{\text{eff}}x \\
\\
&\omega = \sqrt{(k + \frac{q^2}{16\pi\epsilon_0 a^3}) / m} \\
\end{align}

Comment: Sorry, but I have to comment immediately--I love it when a physics problem goes through the trouble of telling you something is a sphere only to almost immediately tell you that the size (i.e. shape) doesn't matter.  So let's just right away start with point masses--instead of spheres.

Comment: If $x\ll1$ then how does $x^2$ fare in comparison to $x$?

Comment: $x^2$ can be ignored.

Comment: And also $(1+x)^n\sim 1+nx$

Comment: Could it be that you need to use the result for the earlier part to see that the two terms that they drop are actually equal and opposite?

Comment: They drop the terms that don't depend on x because they are specifically looking for the $k_e$ in the form of $F=k_e x$, so only terms of $x$ are relevant. The lower order terms would have been present without the displacement anyway, so those aren't part of the new, effective restoring force

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For part (i), the separation doubles when the charges are +q each.

The force at that moment is

$$F = \frac{q^2}{4\pi \epsilon_0 (2a)^2}$$

Now they are connected to *two* identical springs (not shown, I imagine these go to "opposite walls") meaning that each spring will be compressed by $\frac{a}{2}$.

It follows that

$$k\frac{a}{2} = \frac{q^2}{16\pi \epsilon_0 a^2}$$

And that is why those two terms cancel...